# Como isolar a gravidade no acelerômetro

Tags: java, android

Estou desenvolvendo um app em que o usuário precisa chacoalhar o celular para todas as direções e o smartphone precisa manter a orientação estável enquanto isso. O problema é que todas as formas de conseguir orientação espacial como `TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR`, `TYPE_GEOMAGNETIC_ROTATION_VECTOR`, e até o `getRotationMatrix()` usam o acelerômetro em conjunto, e no momento em que o usuário move o celular a direção da gravidade muda devido as forças laterais.

Há algum tipo de filtro para isolar a gravidade? Ou seja isolar os movimentos do usuário, de modo que o sensor retorne somente a direção da gravidade para melhorar a orientação.

Há vários posts sobre como remover a gravidade, mas não há nada sobre isolá-la.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função `getInclination( float[] I )`, ele dá a inclinação somente, em ângulo (radianos). Ou seja, dá a inclinação em relação à força da gravidade.

```
float inclinacao = SensorManager.getInclination(inclinationMatrix);
```

Assim você consegue ajustar a rotação da tela de acordo com o ângulo.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi a pergunta.

O acelerômetro não mede a gravidade, ele mede acelerações, incluindo a da gravidade. Quando você move o celular, a gravidade não "muda", o vetor resultante é que muda.

Se você consegue remover a gravidade, você consegue isolar o vetor dos movimentos do usuário (que vai ser o total menos a gravidade). Se você consegue isolar esse vetor, basta subtrair do total que você obtém a gravidade.